# Cannot download ROS Gazebo 7 packages for Indigo

Tags: git, installation, ubuntu-14.04, package, ros

I'm having some trouble with installing gazebo7_ros_packages for ROS Indigo and Gazebo 7.9 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I followed [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions) tutorial. I typed this

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs
```

The apt installer says the following

```
Unable to locate package ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs
```

I had run sudo update and upgrade before this, and my repositories and keys have been set as given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu).

Terminal screenshot of `sudo apt-get`:

[image: screensho1]

So I tried to clone from OSRF's git from https://github.com/osrf/gazebo7_ros_pkgs-release/tree/debian/indigo/gazebo_ros_pkgs, but I'm only able to pull only one branch at a time. Then I followed [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing) tutorial. This is what I get. Keep in mind, I'm using gazebo 7.9.

Cloning using git:

[image: screenshot2]

I commented on the same question [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/587)

To quote him:

> I don't know the details about your environment, but
>   ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-controlis being successfully installed by our
>   daily testing job:
>   https://build.osrfoundation.org/job/ros_gazebo7_pkgs-install_pkg_indigo-trusty-amd64/274/consoleFull

The URL denotes that it's for a 64 bit machine. I did some poking around on that site and I found out that there are no pkgs for a 32 bit version/i386. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit on a 64  bit Intel Celeron 900. Could that be the problem? Lack of packages for i386 processors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as I guessed, was because of the 32 bit installation of Ubuntu. I reinstalled with a 64 bit version, and it works fine now.

Comment: I have installed it without any problem in a 64-bit version. I don't think it is the problem. In my case, I had to change the PPA url since it was updated in latest version

Answer (score 0):

Have You removed Gazebo 2.* ?
if u didn't already do :

`sudo apt-get purge gazebo*`

after that add the osrf official repo and update:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable lsb_release -cs main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'`

`wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -`

`sudo apt-get update`

and install :

`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs`

found it here [on github](https://github.com/AUV-IITK/AUVWiki/wiki/Installing-Gazebo7-with-ROS-Indigo)